# Install groovy console on Mac and make it runnable from dock

Tags: macos, ide, dock, groovy

How can I install and run Groovy console/IDE from the dock on Mac Sierra?

Comment: Try asking on the apple forum here: https://apple.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Does that 'best solution' work for you? If so you should post it as an answer, and not as part of the question :)

Comment: @bertieb answer converted to community wiki

Comment: Can I have a link to that wiki @

Answer (score 1):

1. Follow these instructions http://sdkman.io/install.html and make sure you restart your terminal session after each step;
2. Say `$ sdk install groovy` to install groovy (I assume you have jdk already installed);
3. Start your Groovy Console in terminal

   ```
   $ ~/.sdkman/candidates/groovy/current/bin/groovyConsole
   ```

   It runs as a separate process;
4. Say `$ ps aux |grep groovy` - you will find out that the console is run as

   > /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_151.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java -Xdock:name=GroovyConsole -Xdock:icon=/Users/yourname/.sdkman/candidates/groovy/current/lib/groovy.icns -classpath /Users/yourname/.sdkman/candidates/groovy/current/lib/groovy-2.4.14.jar -Dscript.name=/Users/yourname/.sdkman/candidates/groovy/current/bin/groovyConsole -Dprogram.name=groovyConsole -Dgroovy.starter.conf=/Users/yourname/.sdkman/candidates/groovy/current/conf/groovy-starter.conf -Dgroovy.home=/Users/yourname/.sdkman/candidates/groovy/current -Dtools.jar=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_151.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/tools.jar org.codehaus.groovy.tools.GroovyStarter --main groovy.ui.Console --conf /Users/yourname/.sdkman/candidates/groovy/current/conf/groovy-starter.conf --classpath .

   I will refer that mess as `jvm-verylongline`
5. Exit the console and start `automator.app`, choose Application and double-click `Run Shell Script` action;
6. Save it as groovyConsole.app to your home folder and exit automator;
7. Edit `~/groovyConsole.app/Contents/Info.plist` and change 3 lines:

   ```
   <key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
   <string>fuckmac</string>
   <key>CFBundleIconFile</key>
   <string>groovy</string>
   <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
   <string>com.apple.groovyConsole</string>
   ```
8. Create file `~/groovyConsole.app/Contents/MacOS/fuckmac` and make it read:

   ```
   #!/bin/bash
   exec -c jvm-verylongline
   ```

   Replacing `jvm-verylongline` as per above, obviously;
9. Say `$ chmod +x ~/groovyConsole.app/Contents/MacOS/fuckmac`
10. As the icon is conveniently named in the `jvm-verylongline`, do

    ```
    $ cp /Users/yourname/.sdkman/candidates/groovy/current/lib/groovy.icns ~/groovyConsole.app/Contents/Resources/
    ```
11. Now you should be able to run the app by double-clicking it in Finder, but probably still with the wrong icon due to caching;
12. Drag-and-drop the app from your home folder to Applications in Finder - this is when the icon malarkey gets fixed;
13. Now you can also drag-and-drop to dock the app.

---

*Note: This solution was originally [posted by the OP](https://superuser.com/revisions/1299953/2) as an edit to the question*